# Чим відрізняється "гривна" від "гривня"?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, вибір-слова

Помітила що російськомовні люди часто кажуть "гривна" замість "гривня". Це калька чи можна казати так і так?

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші критерії якості вимагають, щоб запитання демонструвало спробу автора самостійно відповісти на запитання. Простий пошук за ключовим словом **«гривня гривна правопис»** дає тисячі результатів, більшість з яких — правильні. А якщо автор не докладає зусиль до того, щоб знайти відповідь, то які причини сподіватися, що якісь інші користувачі мають докладати цих зусиль.

Comment: Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [ask] а також
[«Якими мають бути гарні запитання і відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/).
Ви завжди можете виправити запитання, для цього натисніть [edit].

Comment: Дякую, зрозуміла, що, говорячи про гроші, правильно казати "гривня".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Визначення взяті з СУМ online томи 1-8

> **[ГРИВНЯ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=20091&page=680)** 1. Грошова одиниця України (з 1996 р.), що дорівнює 100
>   копійкам.
>   *Приходько легенько вклонився Сані – обличчя поважне, без тіні вини, а переді мною раптом поклав десять гривень* (В. Шкляр).
>
> **[ГРИВНА](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=20090&page=680)**  Металева прикраса у вигляді обруча, яку носили на шиї.
>   *Темне волосся [покійного], зачесане на проділ, прикривала шовкова біла пов'язка .. Єдиний знак великокняжого роду – золота гривна* (С.
>   Скляренко).

Картинка із сайту [Мова - ДНК нація](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/paronimu/gruvnya-j-gruvna)
[image: гривня]